# Jump to an anchor link on function complete in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple slidetoggle function that opens onclick.  What I'd like to do is jump the user down to the bottom of the page following the opened div.  Basically, wait for the slidetoggle to complete - then imagine clicking my jump link to pull the viewport down. Here's my code.

```
 $('#clickme').click(function() {
        $('#form-area').slideToggle('slow', function() {
          // Animation complete
                // what can i put here that's like my standard jumpto?

        });
      });

<a href="#form-bottom" id="clickme">Click here</a>

<div class="main" id="form-area" >
 Stuff
</div>
<a name="form-bottom"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
location.href = '#form-bottom';
```

Comment: That works - thanks much!  Is there a good way to animate smoothly to that position?

Comment: try the scrollto plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)
Very nice and easy to implement

Comment: The requirement changed slightly, so I didn't try the scrollto.  But I found in IE6, location.href forced a page refresh.  As a quick fix - I just added this to jump to the bottom:

dh=document.body.scrollHeight
    ch=document.body.clientHeight
    if(dh>ch){
    moveme=dh-ch
    window.scrollTo(0,moveme)
    }